# How to get latest messages for each user in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have database to store customer and messages

[image]

I am trying to get list of all the customer and their latest messages like first screen in messenger.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM message AS m
LEFT JOIN customer AS c ON c.id=m.sender_id
ORDER BY m.sent_at DESC
```

but this returns all the message for all user. I've also tried doing this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM message AS m
LEFT JOIN customer AS c ON c.id=m.sender_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

but this doesn't run on all databases and cannot sort result set to get latest messages only.

Comment: provide sample data and your desired output in table format

Comment: What if some user have no messages? does this user must be returned with NULL or he must not be returned at all? You use LEFT join - does you have messages which belongs to non-existent users?

Comment: If users don't have messages should not return. I should be using Inner Join it was mistake is question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option uses `row_number()`, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select *    -- better enumerate the columns you want here
from customer as c
left join (
    select m.*, row_number() over(partition by m.sender_id order by sent_at desc) rn
    from messages m
) m on on c.id = m.sender_id and m.rn = 1
order by m.sent_at desc
```

This gives you the last message per customer. You can change the condition on `rn` if you want more messages (`rn <= 3` would give you three messages per customer).

Note that I changed the order of the tables in the `left join`, so it allows customers without messages (rather than messages without customers, which probably does not make sense).

If you are running an earlier version, than an alternative is to filter with a subquery:

```
select *    -- better enumerate the columns you want here
from customer as c
left join messages m 
    on  m.sender_id = c.id
    and sent_at = (select min(m1.sent_at) from messages m1 where m1.sender_id = m.sender_id)
```

For perforamnce with the correlated subquery, consider an index on `(sender_id, sent_at)` (ideally, there should be no duplicates in these columns).

Comment: Interesting answer! You able to explain what is happening here `over(partition...`? I have never seen this.

Comment: @LV98: `row_number()` is a window function; it ranks recodrds having the same sender by descending sent time. You can read more about window functions [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: @GMB it gave error like ```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by m.sender_account_id order by m.sent_at desc ) rn
    from rtc_messa' at line 7.``` mysql version = 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: @KshitijDhakal: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.